# ASP.NET WebApi How to get at the JSON the Controller received

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In my controller:

```
public class ProfileController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage PostCreateProfile (HubBasicProfile bp)
    {

        HttpResponseMessage result = null;    
        if (bp == null)
        {
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Could not instantiate Profile with JSON provided.");
        }


...
```

The automatic deserialization of the json to instantiating a bp object happens in the background.

I want to have a look at the json that that the controller receives to try to resolve an issue that we are experiencing. At this time, bp is always null. (And when I say I want to have a look, I want to inspect it and see where the deserializer is having issues.)

I've looked at the json being sent and that seems to be fine.

So, can anybody tell me how to debug this json -> bp object process?

Comment: Enable tracing and see if the serialiser is logging any warnings http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhenInDoubtTurnOnTracing.aspx

Comment: Make sure the objects that are getting serialized have public setters for their properties!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enable tracing and see if the serialiser is logging any warnings http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhenInDoubtTurnOnTracing.aspx.

Specifically Look here for [tracing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/08/15/asp-net-web-api-released-and-a-preview-of-what-s-next.aspx):

- Add the [Nuget Package](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing)
- Follow the rest of the instructions.

Failing that look [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api) to implement your own very basic one.

Test run your JSON through [JsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Also ensure your Model is correctly defined using something like [Json2C#](http://json2csharp.com/).

Also add a breakpoint and check the `ModelState` property in your controller this may contain some binding errors and warnings.

Comment: Mark, I'd like to turn on the tracing, but we are using MVC4 and the instructions simply say to use Global.aspx.cs but nothing about that cs file is like the previous file that is specified and so, the instructions on how to configure it do not work. :(

Comment: @Eric tried to add more detail - did you add the Nuget package?

Comment: I then tried the ModelState as you suggested and it revealed the issue!!! Thank you very much for all of these. I will am going to try to implement the tracer on my own but for now, am going to accept this since ModelState worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

It should be available in the form collection on the request if you wanted to view it in the debugger